# Initialization error about refraction gem on ruby on rails.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My refraction.rb file inside initializers

```
Refraction.configure do |request|
  if request.host !~ /^www./
    request.permanent! host: "www.#{request.host}" 
  end
end
```

My Environment.rb file under config

```
# Load the rails application.
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  config.middleware.insert_before(::Rack::Lock, ::Refraction, {})
end

require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application.
```

My errors

```
uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)
  /var/www/vhosts/wiyo.hk/httpdocs/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.25/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:105:in `eval'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.25/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:105:in `preload_app'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.25/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:150:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.25/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.25/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

I just wanted to do redirect stuffs before actual website loads. I got to know about refraction gem on previous question. I am stuck. Please help me.

Comment: It looks like you've added the middleware initialization in the wrong place. According to the [gem docs](https://github.com/joshsusser/refraction#installation-rails) you should add it in your `environments/production.rb` file. You've added it before rails is even loaded.

Comment: It seems that the error is on line `Rails::Initializer.run do |config|`... how do you run *Rails*?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve like this, you need to require the application first, and after run that initializer.

But in this times the solution maybe to put that line into the application.rb
And because time passes, `Rack::Lock` is removed. Use `Rack::Runtime` instead.

```rb
config.middleware.insert_before(::Rack::Runtime, ::Refraction)
```